# Unable to open included files

Tags: c, borland-c

I am using BorlandC and Windows 7.

When I compile the file, I am getting these errors:

```
Error Assign.C : Unable to open include file 'stdio.h'
Error Assign.C : Unable to open include file 'conio.h'
Error Assign.C : Unable to open include file 'dos.h'
Error Assign.C : Unable to open include file 'stdlib.h'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've never used Borland, have you specified include directories?

Comment: In include folder all the files stdio.h, conio.h , dos.h  and stdlib.h are exist i have seen these files manually

Comment: Which version of BorlandC++ are you using?
Have you checked if the file that gives errors, has an override of the include directories?
Can you compile successfully other code, like the BC examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check the bcc32.cfg file (should be in the same directory as bcc32.exe) It should contain:

> -ID:\BorlandC\Include

Assuming that the include files can be found in D:\BorlandC\Include

Answer (score 0):

### So I was having the same problem and found the solution:

After installation of Borland, go to bin folder and -

1. Create a bcc32.cfg file while will set the compiler options for the include and lib paths (-I and - L) switches to compiler by adding these lines:

> ```
> -I"C:\Borland\Bcc55\include"
> -L"C:\Borland\Bcc55\lib"
> ```

*My bin folder is in C:\Borland\Bcc55*

2. Create a ilink32.cfg file which will set the linker option for the
   lib path by adding this line:

> ```
> -L"C:\Borland\Bcc55\lib"
> ```

And check if path variable is set for borland compiler which I assume is already set if borland has been installed.
Here's how to check -

- Open **Environment Variables** in **System Properties** > **Advanced** tab.
- Double click on **Path** in System Variables** section.
  Here it should have something like `C:\Borland\Bcc55\Bin` , and if it's not there, then add this path by clicking new. Click **OK**. And you're done.