# borland c unable to include header file

Tags: include, header-files, dosbox, borland-c

I have a very old C project that must be opened using borlandc. my machine runs win 8 so I have installed dosbox to run borlandc

the problem is that when i build the project, there exist too many errors, all are in the form: "unable to include file "xxx.h"

kindly be noted that:
- all these header files are existing in the INCLUDE folder
- I have created the cfg file and set the correct path to that folder for the compiler, so as for the linker
- I have set the environment variables

and still have the same errors

can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `bcc32.cfg`file.It must be in the same directory as that of the `bcc32.exe` file..

Check this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691236/unable-to-open-included-files).

Comment: by the way I'm using BorlandC 3.1 not 5.5